# Does ExcelDataReader for C# require Excel to be installed on the target machine?

Tags: c#, excel-reader

Does [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) for C# require Excel to be installed on the machine the C# code is executing on?

Some packages (such as [Aspose](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net)) explicitly state that they are independent of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` libraries:

> Aspose.Cells for .NET ... does not rely on Microsoft Excel or any Microsoft Office Interop components

I cannot find any explicit statement like the above for the `ExcelDataReader`.

Comment: Almost certainly it doesn't require Excel. 1) what would be the point of it if it did? 2) there is [no mention of interop in the code](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/search?q=interop&type=code)

Comment: Okay, thanks @stuartd. Was just looking for some validation that it didn't have any dependencies on Excel. I can mark yours as the answer if you put it as an answer. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the way that ExcelDataReader works does not depend on having Excel on the machine.  ExcelDataReader does not use the Excel program to read/parse an Excel file.